# How to read a CSV file that contains no headers using Pandas, capture data in the first column only and perform deletion?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that contains information about people and all sorts of data that takes up more than 100 columns. There are no headers and my main **intention is to grab the peoples' names only**. Not the other data related to it. How can I do this?

This is my CSV file --- 'data.csv':

```
John   12 34 23 48 14 44 94 24  ...    #extends till 100
Becky  23 40 93 47 84 43 64 31  ...    #extends till 100
Lio    63 90 53 77 14 12 69 20  ...    #extends till 100
```

Following this, let's say I have a list in my code that is populated with lots of names:

```
names = ['Timothy', 'Joshua', 'Rio', 'Catherine', 'Poorva', 'Gome', 'Lachlan', 'John', 'Lio']
```

I opened my CSV file in Python and used list comprehension in order to read all the names in the first column and store them in a list with a variable 'people_list' assigned.

Now, for all elements in the people_list, if the element is not seen in the 'names' list, I want to delete that element in my CSV file. In this example, I want to delete Becky since she does not appear in the names list. This is what I tried so far...

**Demo -- data.py:**

```
names = ['Timothy', 'Joshua', 'Rio', 'Catherine', 'Poorva', 'Gome', 'Lachlan', 'John', 'Lio']
csv_filename = data.csv

with open(csv_filename, 'r') as readfile:
reader = csv.reader(readfile, delimiter=',') 
people_list = [row[0] for row in reader]

for person in people_list:
    if person not in names:
        id = people_list.index(person) #grab the index of the person in people_list who's not found in the names list.

        #using pandas
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename) #read data.csv file
        df.drop(df.index[id], in_place = True) #delete the row id for the person who does not exist in names list.
        df.to_csv(csv_filename, index = False, sep=',')  #close the csv file with no index
    else:
        print("This person is found in the names list")
```

Instead of deleting Becky, all the records in my CSV file were deleted (including Becky). Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `header=None` to `read_csv` for default columns `0,1,2`...:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename,  header=None)

names = ['Timothy', 'Joshua', 'Rio', 'Catherine', 'Poorva', 'Gome', 'Lachlan', 'John', 'Lio']
```

Then select first column by `df[0]` and test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df[0].isin(names)]
print (df)
```

Last write to file:

```
df.to_csv(csv_filename1, index = False, header=None)
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you Jezrael, this is what I wanted. :)

Comment: @danny_boy - I simplify it by `df[0]` - it get first column and test with `isin` for membership, also please check [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: I will. Pandas is really helpful. If you don't mind, can you please tell me where did you learn it? I mean, do you know any good resource apart from the documentation? The documentation is a bit difficult for me to read. Nevertheless, thanks again!

Comment: @danny_boy - 4 years everydat coding, not easy way for me. I find really good blog, you can check it [link](https://www.dataschool.io/)

Comment: Just one more thing, instead of using: df[df[0].isin(name)]... can I use: df = df[df.iloc[:, 0].isin(name)]?  What is the difference between these two?

Comment: @danny_boy - sure, it is seelct by first column by position, it was my first answer, working nice too.